# Alternative to Websocket?

Tags: websocket

What are good alternatives to websocket?

Comment: You haven't adequately described why you think you need websockets in the first place.  And your detail about *"can’t manage the order in which the functions are called in the server"* doesn't make much sense.  Can you try rephrasing your entire question?

Comment: Rewrite your question starting with 1) What are you trying to do? (presumably something with notifications and a web app).  2) This issue at hand - the reason why you think can't use web sockets. 3) If possible, what you have already tried.  Read this: [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

The Best alternative to web socket is Socket.io

https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io

Comment: Socket.io uses the WebSocket API under the hood unless explicitly set to the use polling, which is intended only for legacy browser support.